# metodo setTimeout() no funcionar al ejecutar la función con click

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Tengo un botón para subir hasta arriba la página al clickar en el. Me funciona perfectamente, cuando clickeo en el me sube hacia arriba y a velocidad smooth.
Pero lo que quiero es que cuando le de al botón espere 2 segundos y ya se ejecute, y no se que estoy haciendo mal que no funciona.

este es mi codigo

```
const returnTopButton = document.querySelector("#returnTop"); //disparador
const targetScroll = document.querySelector("#top"); //objetivo
setTimeout(
returnTopButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  targetScroll.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}),
2000 //tiene que tardar 2 segundos desde que hago click para que se ejecute la función
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debe ser al revés, en el listener del evento debes meter toda tú lógica, esto se asocia 1 vez al elemento y todo lo que haya dentro de él se ejecutará. Intenta:

```
const returnTopButton = document.querySelector("#returnTop"); //disparador
const targetScroll = document.querySelector("#top"); //objetivo

returnTopButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    targetScroll.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  },2000);      
});
```

Comment: Perfecto, funciona. Ahora entiendo mejor como se usan los `setTimeOut()`. para las próximas veces jeje.